# Find the general values and principal values of $i^{log(i+1)}$?

Tags: complex-numbers

Find the general values of $i^{\log(i+1)}$?

I tried this way...
$\log(i+1)\log(i)=[\log \sqrt2+i(2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{4})]*i(2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2})$

Comment: What you have is correct.To finish, write the RHS as $x+i y$ with real $x,y .$  Then $i^{\log (i+1)}=e^{x+i y}=e^x (\cos y+i \sin y).$

Comment: Sometimes it is convenient to use the abbreviation $cis (y)=\cos y+i \sin y$.

Comment: @user254665 I finally have $e^{-(4n^2\pi^2+\frac{3}{2}n\pi^2+\frac{\pi^2}{8})}cis(log\sqrt2)$.

Comment: Why use the same integer $n$ in the determinations of $\log(1+i)$  and $\log(i)$?

Comment: @Did yes both integers are different. In case they are equal, Is my expression okay?

Comment: Yes but I overlooked that you should have an m and an n in log(i+1)log i to include all possible values

Answer (score 2):

Using complex natural logarithm, i.e., $\log z=\log(x+iy)=\log(|
z|e^{i(\phi+2\pi n)})=\log|z|+i(\phi+2\pi n)$

$$i^{\log(1+i)}=e^{\log i\cdot\log(1+i)}=e^{(\log 1 + i(\pi/2+2\pi n))\cdot(\log\sqrt{2}+i(\pi/4+2\pi k))}=e^{\frac{1}{2}\log{2}(i\pi/2+i2\pi n)-(\pi/2+2\pi n)(\pi/4+2\pi k)}=$$
Final simplification:
$$=e^{-\pi^2/8+\pi^2k+\pi^2/2n+4\pi^2nk}e^{i\pi/2\log 2(1/2+2n)}$$

For the main branch, i.e., $k=0$, $n=0$, the result is
$$e^{-\frac{\pi^2}{8}}e^{i\pi\frac{\log 2}{4}}\approx 0.2912 e^{i0.544}\approx0.24912+0.1508i$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $ log (i+1)=log (\sqrt {2})+\dfrac {i\pi}{4}$ , then $i^{log(i+1)}=i^{log (\sqrt {2})}i^{i\pi/4}$, with $i^{i\pi/4}=e^{-\pi^{2}/8}e^{-2k\pi^{2} /4}$.

Comment: How to proceed in this case.. $i^{e^i}$?

Answer (score -2):

$i^{\log(1+i)}$

$=(1+i)^{\log i}$

$=(1+i)^{i(4n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}}$

$=\left(\sqrt{2} e^{i(2k\pi}+\frac{\pi}{4})\right)^{i(4n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}}$

$=2^{i(4n+1)\frac{\pi}{4}}e^{-(2k+1)(4n+1)\frac{{\pi}^2}{8}}$

For principal value putting $n=k=0$ we get $i^{\log(1+i)}=2^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}.e^{-\frac{{\pi}^2}{8}}$

Comment: Why $i^{\log(1+i)}=(1+i)^{\log i}$?

Comment: $a^{\log b}=b^{\log a}$

Comment: Huh? Why? Using which definition of the logarithm?

Comment: Read again $a^{\log b}=b^{\log a}$.Here $a=i$ and $b=1+i$

Comment: Being obnoxious to compensate for the fact that you do not know what you are talking about? Quote: `Using which definition of the logarithm?`

Comment: Ok I will prove it. Let $k=a^{\log b}$.So, $\log k=log a^{\log b}$.Thus,$\log k=log b \log a=log a \log b=log b^{\log a}$.Now,take anti-log on both sides to get $k=b^{\log a}$. Thus $a^{\log b}=b^{\log a}$. I hope you find it satisfactory.

Comment: I was not being obnoxious.Sorry you felt that way.

Comment: "I hope you find it satisfactory" Really not--this uses freely rules of computations only valid for the logarithms of nonnegative real numbers. Here the logarithms are applied to complex numbers. (Rather tellingly, the OP cannot provide a *definition* of the logarithm in this wider context.)

Comment: Then we should not be having logarithms in complex numbers

Comment: @Litun John. The identity is correct.

Comment: @Did. What is OP.

Comment: @PankajSinha You are correct.

Comment: @PankajSinha I got $e^{−(4n^2\pi^2+\frac{3}{2}n\pi^2+\frac{\pi^2}{8})}cis(\log\sqrt2)$ assuming $k=n$.

Comment: @Litun John .$\cis(log]sqrt{2}$ is ok. Elaborate how you get the other factor.

Comment: @PankajSinha. $i^{\log(i+1)}=e^{\log(i+1)\log i}=e^{[\log\sqrt2 +i (2n\pi+\pi/4)]*i(2n\pi+\pi/4)}$

Comment: @PankajSinha "Then we should not be having logarithms in complex numbers" What? Of course one can manipulate logarithms of complex numbers--only, as already mentioned, one should be aware that every rule valid for logarithms of positive real numbers does not apply to logarithms of complex numbers. (Still no definition in view?)